# sql server 2014 combining data with column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table like this

```
Customerno |  8-10  | 10-12 | 12-14     |    14-16   |  16-18   |     18-20|

    1        null     null    Thursday       null       null         null
    2        friday   null     null          null       wednesday     monday
```

I want a table like this based on above table

```
 customerno | monday(8-10)| monday(10-12)| monday(12-14) |         |friday(18-20)

1               false         false            false                    false
2              false           false           false                     false
```

true only if the customer called on that time and day

how should i do that?

Comment: Please format your question so that it's more clear to others ... you can specify code by wrapping `code` with \` like this  \`code\`.

Comment: that design would be unadvisable.

Comment: Unless you do that for performance reasons, as Mitch Wheat says, you should rethink your logic. Please specify what is it that you are trying to achievie and we will guide you to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its very long code, i could not find any other way to do this so:

```
DECLARE @CUSTOMER TABLE
(
CUSTOMERID INT,
[MONDAY(8-10)] VARCHAR(10),[MONDAY(10-12)] VARCHAR(10),[MONDAY(12-14)] VARCHAR(10),
[MONDAY(14-16)] VARCHAR(10),[MONDAY(16-18)] VARCHAR(10),[MONDAY(18-20)] VARCHAR(10),
[TUESDAY(8-10)] VARCHAR(10),[TUESDAY(10-12)] VARCHAR(10),[TUESDAY(12-14)] VARCHAR(10),
[TUESDAY(14-16)] VARCHAR(10),[TUESDAY(16-18)] VARCHAR(10),[TUESDAY(18-20)] VARCHAR(10),
[WEDNESDAY(8-10)] VARCHAR(10),[WEDNESDAY(10-12)] VARCHAR(10),[WEDNESDAY(12-14)] VARCHAR(10),
[WEDNESDAY(14-16)] VARCHAR(10),[WEDNESDAY(16-18)] VARCHAR(10),[WEDNESDAY(18-20)] VARCHAR(10),
[THURSDAY(8-10)] VARCHAR(10),[THURSDAY(10-12)] VARCHAR(10),[THURSDAY(12-14)] VARCHAR(10),
[THURSDAY(14-16)] VARCHAR(10),[THURSDAY(16-18)] VARCHAR(10),[THURSDAY(18-20)] VARCHAR(10),
[FRIDAY(8-10)] VARCHAR(10),[FRIDAY(10-12)] VARCHAR(10),[FRIDAY(12-14)] VARCHAR(10),
[FRIDAY(14-16)] VARCHAR(10),[FRIDAY(16-18)] VARCHAR(10),[FRIDAY(18-20)] VARCHAR(10)
)
DECLARE @ID INT,@810 VARCHAR(10),@1012 VARCHAR(10),@1214 VARCHAR(10),@1416 VARCHAR(10),@1618 VARCHAR(10),@1820 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @MONDAY810 VARCHAR(10),@MONDAY1012 VARCHAR(10),@MONDAY1214 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @MONDAY1416 VARCHAR(10),@MONDAY1618 VARCHAR(10),@MONDAY1820 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @TUESDAY810 VARCHAR(10),@TUESDAY1012 VARCHAR(10),@TUESDAY1214 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @TUESDAY1416 VARCHAR(10),@TUESDAY1618 VARCHAR(10),@TUESDAY1820 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @WEDNESDAY810 VARCHAR(10),@WEDNESDAY1012 VARCHAR(10),@WEDNESDAY1214 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @WEDNESDAY1416 VARCHAR(10),@WEDNESDAY1618 VARCHAR(10),@WEDNESDAY1820 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @THURSDAY810 VARCHAR(10),@THURSDAY1012 VARCHAR(10),@THURSDAY1214 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @THURSDAY1416 VARCHAR(10),@THURSDAY1618 VARCHAR(10),@THURSDAY1820 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @FRIDAY810 VARCHAR(10),@FRIDAY1012 VARCHAR(10),@FRIDAY1214 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @FRIDAY1416 VARCHAR(10),@FRIDAY1618 VARCHAR(10),@FRIDAY1820 VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE C CURSOR FOR 
SELECT CUSTOMERNO,[8-10],[10-12],[12-14],[14-16],[16-18],[18-20] FROM CUSTOMER
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @ID,@810,@1012,@1214,@1416,@1618,@1820
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
----// 8-10 //----------
    IF @810 LIKE '%MONDAY%'     SET  @MONDAY810='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @810 LIKE '%TUESDAY%'       SET  @TUESDAY810='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @810 LIKE '%WEDNESDAY%'     SET  @WEDNESDAY810='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @810 LIKE '%THURSDAY%'      SET  @THURSDAY810='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @810 LIKE '%FRIDAY%'        SET  @FRIDAY810='TRUE'
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET  @MONDAY810='False'
            SET  @TUESDAY810='False'
            SET  @WEDNESDAY810='False'
            SET  @THURSDAY810='False'
            SET  @FRIDAY810='False'
        END
----// 10-12 //----------
    IF @1012 LIKE '%MONDAY%'        SET  @MONDAY1012='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1012 LIKE '%TUESDAY%'      SET  @TUESDAY1012='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1012 LIKE '%WEDNESDAY%'        SET  @WEDNESDAY1012='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1012 LIKE '%THURSDAY%'     SET  @THURSDAY1012='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1012 LIKE '%FRIDAY%'       SET  @FRIDAY1012='TRUE'
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET  @MONDAY1012='False'
            SET  @TUESDAY1012='False'
            SET  @WEDNESDAY1012='False'
            SET  @THURSDAY1012='False'
            SET  @FRIDAY1012='False'
        END

----// 12-14 //----------
    IF @1214 LIKE '%MONDAY%'        SET  @MONDAY1214='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1214 LIKE '%TUESDAY%'      SET  @TUESDAY1214='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1214 LIKE '%WEDNESDAY%'        SET  @WEDNESDAY1214='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1214 LIKE '%THURSDAY%'     SET  @THURSDAY1214='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1214 LIKE '%FRIDAY%'       SET  @FRIDAY1214='TRUE'
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET  @MONDAY1214='False'
            SET  @TUESDAY1214='False'
            SET  @WEDNESDAY1214='False'
            SET  @THURSDAY1214='False'
            SET  @FRIDAY1214='False'
        END

----// 14-16//----------
    IF @1416 LIKE '%MONDAY%'        SET  @MONDAY1416='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1416 LIKE '%TUESDAY%'      SET  @TUESDAY1416='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1416 LIKE '%WEDNESDAY%'        SET  @WEDNESDAY1416='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1416 LIKE '%THURSDAY%'     SET  @THURSDAY1416='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1416 LIKE '%FRIDAY%'       SET  @FRIDAY1416='TRUE'
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET  @MONDAY1416='False'
            SET  @TUESDAY1416='False'
            SET  @WEDNESDAY1416='False'
            SET  @THURSDAY1416='False'
            SET  @FRIDAY1416='False'
        END

----// 16-18 //----------
    IF @1618 LIKE '%MONDAY%'        SET  @MONDAY1618='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1618 LIKE '%TUESDAY%'      SET  @TUESDAY1618='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1618 LIKE '%WEDNESDAY%'        SET  @WEDNESDAY1618='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1618 LIKE '%THURSDAY%'     SET  @THURSDAY1618='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1618 LIKE '%FRIDAY%'       SET  @FRIDAY1618='TRUE'
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET  @MONDAY1618='False'
            SET  @TUESDAY1618='False'
            SET  @WEDNESDAY1618='False'
            SET  @THURSDAY1618='False'
            SET  @FRIDAY1618='False'
        END

----// 18-20 //----------
    IF @1820 LIKE '%MONDAY%'    SET  @MONDAY1820='TRUE' ELSE
     IF @1820 LIKE '%TUESDAY%'      SET  @TUESDAY1820='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1820 LIKE '%WEDNESDAY%'        SET  @WEDNESDAY1820='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1820 LIKE '%THURSDAY%'     SET  @THURSDAY1820='TRUE'
    ELSE IF @1820 LIKE '%FRIDAY%'       SET  @FRIDAY1820='TRUE'
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET  @MONDAY1820='False'
            SET  @TUESDAY1820='False'
            SET  @WEDNESDAY1820='False'
            SET  @THURSDAY1820='False'
            SET  @FRIDAY1820='False'
        END
IF @MONDAY810     IS NULL SET  @MONDAY810 ='TRUE'    
IF @MONDAY1012    IS NULL SET  @MONDAY1012  ='TRUE'
IF @MONDAY1214    IS NULL SET  @MONDAY1214   ='TRUE' 
IF @MONDAY1416    IS NULL SET  @MONDAY1416   ='TRUE' 
IF @MONDAY1618    IS NULL SET  @MONDAY1618   ='TRUE' 
IF @MONDAY1820    IS NULL SET  @MONDAY1820   ='TRUE' 
IF @TUESDAY810    IS NULL SET  @TUESDAY810   ='TRUE' 
IF @TUESDAY1012   IS NULL SET  @TUESDAY1012  ='TRUE' 
IF @TUESDAY1214   IS NULL SET  @TUESDAY1214  ='TRUE' 
IF @TUESDAY1416   IS NULL SET  @TUESDAY1416  ='TRUE' 
IF @TUESDAY1618   IS NULL SET  @TUESDAY1618  ='TRUE' 
IF @TUESDAY1820   IS NULL SET  @TUESDAY1820  ='TRUE' 
IF @WEDNESDAY810  IS NULL SET  @WEDNESDAY810 ='TRUE' 
IF @WEDNESDAY1012 IS NULL SET  @WEDNESDAY1012='TRUE' 
IF @WEDNESDAY1214 IS NULL SET  @WEDNESDAY1214='TRUE' 
IF @WEDNESDAY1416 IS NULL SET  @WEDNESDAY1416='TRUE' 
IF @WEDNESDAY1618 IS NULL SET  @WEDNESDAY1618='TRUE' 
IF @WEDNESDAY1820 IS NULL SET  @WEDNESDAY1820='TRUE' 
IF @THURSDAY810   IS NULL SET  @THURSDAY810  ='TRUE' 
IF @THURSDAY1012  IS NULL SET  @THURSDAY1012 ='TRUE' 
IF @THURSDAY1214  IS NULL SET  @THURSDAY1214 ='TRUE' 
IF @THURSDAY1416  IS NULL SET  @THURSDAY1416 ='TRUE' 
IF @THURSDAY1618  IS NULL SET  @THURSDAY1618 ='TRUE' 
IF @THURSDAY1820  IS NULL SET  @THURSDAY1820 ='TRUE' 
IF @FRIDAY810     IS NULL SET  @FRIDAY810    ='TRUE' 
IF @FRIDAY1012    IS NULL SET  @FRIDAY1012   ='TRUE' 
IF @FRIDAY1214    IS NULL SET  @FRIDAY1214   ='TRUE' 
IF @FRIDAY1416    IS NULL SET  @FRIDAY1416   ='TRUE' 
IF @FRIDAY1618    IS NULL SET  @FRIDAY1618   ='TRUE' 
IF @FRIDAY1820    IS NULL SET  @FRIDAY1820   ='TRUE' 

INSERT INTO @CUSTOMER 
VALUES
( @ID,@MONDAY810 ,@MONDAY1012 ,@MONDAY1214,
 @MONDAY1416 ,@MONDAY1618 ,@MONDAY1820, 
 @TUESDAY810 ,@TUESDAY1012 ,@TUESDAY1214, 
 @TUESDAY1416 ,@TUESDAY1618 ,@TUESDAY1820, 
 @WEDNESDAY810 ,@WEDNESDAY1012 ,@WEDNESDAY1214, 
 @WEDNESDAY1416 ,@WEDNESDAY1618 ,@WEDNESDAY1820, 
 @THURSDAY810 ,@THURSDAY1012 ,@THURSDAY1214, 
 @THURSDAY1416 ,@THURSDAY1618 ,@THURSDAY1820, 
 @FRIDAY810 ,@FRIDAY1012 ,@FRIDAY1214, 
 @FRIDAY1416 ,@FRIDAY1618 ,@FRIDAY1820 )

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @ID,@810,@1012,@1214,@1416,@1618,@1820
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C

SELECT * FROM @CUSTOMER
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply 
any other easy way by using Pivot
It is not for performance it is a requirement

Thanks